# Which Ubuntu version is good for AI?

Tags: tensorflow

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and because of my CPU not supporting AVX, I'm having a lot trouble with latest versions of the software. The old version are difficult to find and not running as they should.

What previous version of Ubuntu would be suitable for my system? I seem to require Python3.6, CUDA9, CudNN7, Tensorflow below 1.15. Which previous version of Ubuntu will install these versions as default if I type for example, sudo apt install tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 toolchain has Python3.6 installed by default. The default Ubuntu repositories have NVIDIA CUDA Runtime Library (*libcudart9.1*). TensorFlow 1.15 stable release for either CPU or GPU can be downloaded manually from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow. Don't install any other supporting packages for TensorFlow before checking the requirements of the TensorFlow package that you intend to install.

[Extended Security Maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/esm) (ESM) extends Ubuntu's support lifetime from 5 years to 10 years. ESM is free for personal use on up to 3 machines (limitations apply). All you need is an Ubuntu One account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what version GCC does it have?

Comment: The installation instructions on Tensorflow website say I have to either create a virtual environment and use pip to install or use apt, both of them are installing versions 2.0 which is incompatible with my system.

Comment: Tensorflow website doesn't give download links

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has the following gcc versions: 4.8/5/6/7/8, and the default gcc version is 7.4. I added the download link to TensorFlow 1.15 to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to downgrade to 18.04 keeping my files?

Comment: For what you are planning to do backup your files and do a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 is the preferred option. One ext4 partition is all you need for a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04. If your computer also requires a 100-500MB EFI System Partition the Ubuntu installer will create one automatically.